# Convert HDMI video to Coaxial Antenna?

Tags: hdmi

I need to take an HDMI (unencrypted source) from a Sony video camera and send it via coaxial cables which are hooked directly to TVs wired throughout the building. I'd like to be able to tune into i.e. Channel 3 to tune into the video signal.

I've searched and the only solution I can find is an SDI to HDMI converter, but I'd rather not use that and would prefer to hook coax directly to the TV as below:

```
Camera (HDMI) --> [CONVERTER BOX??] ==coaxial==> TV
                                     |=========> TV
                                     `=========> TV  (etc)
```

Comment: What you are looking for is a device like this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Edision-HDMI-Modulator-Full-Distribution/dp/B00KBXKJ2A

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want digital channel 3, you can use an HDMI to QAM modulator, like [this one](https://www.zeevee.com/zvpro-800i-series-hd-video-distribution.html) or [this one](http://www.blondertongue.com/UserFiles/file/documents/specs/HDE-CHV-QAM_IP_SpecSheet_042816.pdf). You will need appropriate multiplexers, amplifiers, and splitters to combine your feed with your CATV provider and then distribute to the TVs.

If you need *analog* channel 3, then it is more complicated. You will probably first need to convert to SDI, then convert to analog video and audio, and finally feed an analog modulator.

Comment: I think QAM would be sufficient -- these will be going to LCD TVs with standard Cable TV input. There isn't any other use for the TV besides displaying the camera feed. (Currently it's displaying a low res component yellow cable signal and looks crappy.)  If there are any other cheaper alternatives, I'd be happy to hear them.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, @JonasCz has suggested the perfect solution for your question. There are several similar products like this that will take HDMI HD video input (from your camera) and output a digital TV channel signal to send to the antenna inputs of all your TV receivers.

Note that you will need RG6 cable (or at least RG59 for short distances).  Your present cable (for composite video) may not be suitable for RF.

If that is not good enough quality, you should consider converting the camera HDMI to SDI so that you can distribute full-quality HD video to all the screens (assuming they have HDMI inputs.)  You will need an HDMI->SDI converter at the camera and a SDI->HDMI converter at each screen.

If you get the kind of SDI->HDMI converters with "loop-through", you can daisy-chain the SDI video from one screen to the next. This could save some budget in cables.  Note that you can use quite inexpensive RG6 as used for wiring cable and satellite TV. Less than $US100 per 1000 foot roll, etc.

Comment: Well I almost answered this, but I'm in the USA and that product doesn't appear to be sold here.. either because it is illegal(?) or won't work(?). Any thoughts about getting something like that in the states?

Comment: That is one of the deficiencies of this website, they strip away any location information which is critical for questions like this.  You need a "HDMI ATSC modulator", and to my surprise, there are no inexpensive solutions to this problem.  There are $100-300 solutions for TV standards in other parts of the world, but not for ATSC in North America.  You may be stuck with distributing SDI and using an inexpensive HDMI to SDI converter for the camera and SDI to HDMI converter boxes for each screen.  Upside: it will be significantly higher quality than encoding onto a TV channel.